# Смена эпох в стране: Библиотека — Дискотека — Ипотека

Tags: выбор-слов, прописная-строчная, названия

Смена эпох в стране: Библиотека — Дискотека — Ипотека.

Анекдот, но как таковые эпохи типа застоя пишутся с маленькой буквы, здесь по аналогии так же?

Answer (score 1):

Заглавные, но в кавычках.
Тире тоже не нужны.

Смена эпох в стране: "Библиотека", "Дискотека", "Ипотека".

С Возрождением не равняйте, это узаконенное исторической наукой название, у вас тоже названия, но больше напоминает название колхоза - как раз периода "библиотеки" (вот у меня не название).

> так уже несмешно)

Анекдот не особо смешной в любом случае.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, ну никак не "вписывается" этот текст в рамки правил. Предлагаю свой варинат.

Эпохи развития страны:

- библиотечная
- дискотечная
- ипотечная

Comment: так уже несмешно)

Comment: или просто понизить.....

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае понижать название "эпох" нельзя, т.к. тогда будет превалировать общеупотребительное, обычное значение слов. С другой стороны есть прецеденты написания названия эпох с заглавной буквы (Возрождение). Оба аргумента - за вами приведенное написание (с б.б.).